# Does anyone know how to create and delete a category with channels in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get my discord bot to create a category that has 3 distinct channels, each with different permissions. I would also like a way to delete this category entirely at the end of my code. Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. Here are 3 of them:

Putting parent in channel create options:

```js
guild.channels.create("chan-name", {
  parent: "123456789012345678" // the ID of the category channel
})
```

Using [`CategoryChannel#createChannel()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/CategoryChannel?scrollTo=createChannel)

```js
category.createChannel("chan-name")
```

And lastly, not recommended though, is assigning after creation. It's not recommended as it does 2 API requests rather than 1

```js
let channel = await guild.channels.create("chan-name")
channel.setParent("category-id")
```

Comment: And you can delete channel with ```channel.delete()```